# Filter nested array in javascript without affecting references

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

first post,

I'm working in next.js, and have created a function to filter posts. It works fine if the posts are collected un-nessted in an array e.g. ObjChild. In another section of my site I have an array of parent posts, within each is an array of child posts. When I filter the posts on any part of my site it effects the whole site, and I cannot return to the original array, which I can in the simplified version by just using setState(original)

Example data structure:

```
// Collection Index File

const Collection = [
    ObjParent1: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: [
            ObjChild1 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            },
            ObjChild2 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            },
            ObjChild-n {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            }
        ]
    },  
    ObjParent2: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: [
            objChild1 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            }
        ]
    },  
    ObjParent3: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: [
            objChild1 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            }
        ]
    }   
]
```

I think my issue is to do with deeply nested arrays, in the first instance, it is a shallow array so array.map is returning a new array of primitive values. With the nested example, the ObjChild still holds reference values. How do I get around this? I tried using array.splice() but had no change. I thought by assigning a new cost I was overcoming this, but turns out it is just more references.

Example code:

```
// Page.js

const postFilter = (collection, tag) => {
    const newarray = collection
    newarray.map((objParent) => {
        objParent.children = objParent.children.filter(({tags}) => {
            return (tags.find(element => element == tag)) ? true : false
        });
    });
    return newarray
};

function Page(Collection) {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState(Collection);
    
    function filterPosts(clicked) {
        const tag = clicked.currentTarget.value
        setPosts(postFilter(posts, tag))
    }
    
    return (
        posts.map( //...... maps Collection
            <button value='tag' onClick={filterPosts}>button</button>
    )
}
```

The end goal is to be able to filter by tag without affecting the initial object.

```
// example output

when button value = 'tag1'

Collection = [
    ObjParent1: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: [
            ObjChild1 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1']
            },
            ObjChild2 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag3']
            },
        ]
    },  
    ObjParent2: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: [
            objChild1 {
            idchild: 'abc'
            infochild: 'abc'
            tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
            }
        ]
    },  
    ObjParent3: {
        id: 'abc'
        info: 'abc'
        children: []
    }
```

Thanks for you help! (let me know if there is an easier way to ask this)

Comment: Could you share your input and your expected output ?

Comment: `array.map` and `array.filter` both return new array references, so it isn't clear if you are instead doing something else that is mutating your data. The code in your `postFilter` function also isn't correct. You are just returning `postarray` value, I think you meant to return the result of `newarray.map`.

Comment: What is the `proj.challenges` object? You ***are*** mutating that in the `postFilter` callback with some filtered result, i.e. `proj.challenges = proj.challenges.filter(......)`.

Comment: @NghiNguyen input is similar to the example, i'll add an example output.

Comment: @DrewReese not quite, array.map only does a shallow copy, so .challenges continues to contain references. When I modify it I modify the referenced object.
I'll update the example I mixed some thing up when I tried to make it more reproducible

Comment: is collection an array? what about the cildren? please add valid data (copy paste ready). btw, do you want to get an empty parent as well?

Comment: Not quite what? "shallow copy" is essentially what is meant by "a new array reference" is returned. `.map` and `.filter` are pure functions but you are mutating some `proj.challenges` object (now `objParent.children = objParent.children.filter`), which is a side-effect. I was trying to point out that if you were using these two functions correctly you wouldn't be seeing the issue of "affecting references", i.e. the stuff that was shallowly copied.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are mutating your state object. On top of that you aren't returning a new array reference from the `postFilter` utility for updating state. You map over a reference to your `posts` state and mutate the `children` property.

```
const postFilter = (collection, tag) => {
  const newarray = collection; // <-- reference to posts state

  // no capture of mapped result
  newarray.map((objParent) => {
    // objParent.children property mutation
    objParent.children = objParent.children.filter(({tags}) => {
      return (tags.find(element => element == tag)) ? true : false
    });
  });

  return newarray; // <-- still same posts reference
};
```

## Solution

Return the mapped result. Not only do you need to shallow copy the array into a new array reference, you need to shallow copy any nested state that is also being updated.

```
const postFilter = (collection, tag) => {
  return collection.map(objParent => ({
    ...objParent,
    children: objParent.children.filter(({ tags }) => tags.includes(tag))
  }));
};
```

I suggest also using a functional state update so you ensure the `posts` state is correctly updated from the previous state. This is a small tweak.

```
function filterPosts(clicked) {
  const tag = clicked.currentTarget.value
  setPosts(posts => postFilter(posts, tag))
}
```

```js
const collection = [
  {
    id: "abc",
    info: "abc",
    children: [
      {
        idchild: "abc",
        infochild: "abc",
        tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
      },
      {
        idchild: "abc",
        infochild: "abc",
        tags: ["tag1", "tag4", "tag5"]
      },
      {
        idchild: "abc",
        infochild: "abc",
        tags: ["tag6", "tag7", "tag8"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    info: "abc",
    children: [
      {
        idchild: "abc",
        infochild: "abc",
        tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "abc",
    info: "abc",
    children: [
      {
        idchild: "abc",
        infochild: "abc",
        tags: ["tag4", "tag2", "tag3"]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const postFilter = (collection, tag) => {
  return collection.map(objParent => ({
    ...objParent,
    children: objParent.children.filter(({ tags }) => tags.includes(tag))
  }));
};

const result = postFilter(collection, 'tag1');

console.log(result);
```

## Suggestion

The downside to saving filtered results into state like this though is that if you want to clear any filters you need to go back and reset/re-initialize the `post` state back to the passed `collection`. An improved solution would be to instead store any filtering state as well and filter the `posts` state array inline when rendering.

```
function Page(Collection) {
  const [tag, setTag] = useState('');
    
  function filterPosts(clicked) {
    setTag(clicked.currentTarget.value);
  }
    
  return postFilter(collection, tag).map((post) => ...
    <button value='tag' onClick={filterPosts}>button</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll go test this out. I actually do have a state for tag but that bit was working so I omitted it.

Could you give some detail this syntax? I've not run into it before (pretty new)
`setPosts(posts => postFilter(posts, tag))`

also, I haven't quite nailed spread yet, by using ...objParent, it spreads obj parent so you can directly access children?

Comment: @jsmccid Sure. `setPosts(posts => postFilter(posts, tag))` is a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) used when updates *depend* on previous state. In this case the dependency *is* the previous `posts` state array since we must shallow copy it into the next state object (this is also the Spread Syntax used in the `postFilter` callback). The Spread Syntax is used when shallow copying any nested state properties that are being updated so it has a new object reference and React reconciliation can work. React uses shallow object equality.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the input in correct format. I assume the filter is we have a tag and if any item don't have that tag in tags problem will be filter out off the list.

You can check the implementation below

```js
const originObj = [
    {
        id: 'abc',
        info: 'abc',
        children: [
            {
              idchild: 'abc',
              infochild: 'abc',
              tags: [ 'tag2', 'tag3'],
            },
            {
              idchild: 'abc',
              infochild: 'abc',
              tags: ['tag1',  'tag3'],
            },
           {
              idchild: 'abc',
              infochild: 'abc',
              tags: ['tag1', 'tag5', 'tag3'],
            }
        ]
    },
           {
              idchild: 'ddd',
              infochild: 'abc',
              tags: ['tag1', 'tag5', 'tag3'],
            }
]

const filterFn = (item, tag) => {
  return item.tags.includes(tag)
}

const recursiveFind = (items, tag) => {
  return items.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if(!cur.children || cur.children.length === 0){
      if(filterFn(cur, tag)){
       acc.push(cur)
      }
    } else {
      const newCur = {...cur, children: [...recursiveFind(cur.children, tag)]}
      acc.push(newCur)
    }
    return acc
  },[])
}

const tag = 'tag5'

const newObj = recursiveFind(originObj, tag)

console.log(newObj)
console.log(originObj)
```